# How to efficiently remove items from an associative array using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am working on a project using jQuery and KendoUI for jQuery, and I need to make a method for removing elements by updating it rather then actually mutating the object.

I have concluded that I should be using the spread syntax to identify and remove the object/option I receive as an argument, and then set my new list as the remaining objects/options.

I want to do something akin to this, but I'm slightly uncertain exactly how I can identify the object I want to remove without running a loop - and need advice on how to do this 'best practice'.

```
deleteOption: option => {
                const { option, ...rest } = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods");
                P.Order.Payment.set("paymentMethods", rest);
              }
```

My array consist of objects that are uniquely identified by a `uid`-attribute.

Object in the array are created like this:

```
addNewCard: () => {
                P.Order.Payment.addOption(
                    {
                      paymentName: "Kort",
                      type: "CC",
                      value: 0,
                      class: "form-control",
                      icon: "fal fa-credit-card",
                      validated: true,
                      uid: this.uid,
                      update: (values) => {
                        P.Order.Payment.updateOption(this, values);
                      },
                      rmItem: function(){
                        P.Order.Payment.subtractValue(this.uid);
                        P.Order.Payment.deleteOption(this);
                      }
                    }
                );
              },
```

SOLUTION:

The suggestions below ALMOST got me where I needed, but as the argument I recieve is an object, not a string I needed a string identifier to use them.  As the object in my case always is part of an indexed array though I could use the index as my identifier, I also had to adjust my set method to correctly merge the remaining indexed array without affecting the associative part of the array holding Kendo functions.

```
deleteOption:  option => {
  const index = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods").indexOf(option);
  let { [index]: _, ...rest } = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods");
  rest = Array.from(rest).filter(entry => entry === undefined || null);
  P.Order.Payment.set("paymentMethods", [ ...rest ]);
},
```

This solution solved my problem, I think it's fairly clean but it should have room for optimisation when used outside of KendoUI.

Comment: please add some examples of `option`.

Comment: Added an example of the creator method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a computed property name:

```
deleteOption: option => {
    const { [option]: option, ...rest } = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods");
    P.Order.Payment.set("paymentMethods", rest);
}
```

Comment: Could I then identify it by a property of the object aswell such as maybe: deleteOption: uid => {
    const { [option]: option.uid, ...rest } = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods");
    P.Order.Payment.set("paymentMethods", rest);
}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the key of the variable `option`, you need a computed property with a dummy variable.

```
deleteOption: option => {
    const { [option]:_, ...rest } = P.Order.Payment.get("paymentMethods");
    P.Order.Payment.set("paymentMethods", rest);
}
```